# Need correct syntax for using a role with chef knife ec2

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to use knife ec2 from examples that I've seen online but for whatever reason the --run-list option is not recognizing that I am supplying it a role:

```
knife ec2 server create --run-list 'role[linux_server]' -I  ami-9aaa1cf2 -f t2.small  -S chef -i C:\Users\admin\Documents\Dev\Chef\chef.pem --ssh-user ubuntu --subnet subnet-xxxxxxx --associate-eip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I get this error:

```
 resolving cookbooks for run list: ["roles"]


 Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:


 Missing Cookbooks:
 ------------------
 The following cookbooks are required by the client but don't exist on the server:
 * roles


 Expanded Run List:
 ------------------
 * roles
```

Comment: Could you show us your role definition?

Comment: The error is searching for a `roles` cookbook, with a **s** at  end.. without your `linux_server` role content, it's impossible to guess what's wrong inside it.

Comment: The contents are these cookbooks:
chef_handler
chef-client::config
chef-client::init_service
host_file_linux
resolver
sysctl
sysctl::apply

Comment: I added the "roles" cookbook to my chef server and the instance starts and only runs the roles cookbook. I look at the run list on the chef server and it's empty.... not sure what I'm missing here...

Comment: Use some paste (pastebin?) service and please put your role code there.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FEH2uDxZ

Comment: I should mention this role works fine on vagrant build locally.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you didn't write `--run-list 'roles[linux_server]'`?